# How to replace the value of a field by another on submit event?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In React-Admin, on our sign up form ( SimpleForm ), to increase security and the trust of our users, we don't want that our server receive the user password in clear text (even if we are in HTTPS).

We would like to replace the value on-the-fly with the associated sha256 hash (on the server side we store the bcrypt version of this hash)

There is a solution to do that without any change of the value in the SimpleForm from the user point of view ? Because, if the server API return an error in the form, the user will re-submit another time the form and we still need to translate the original password value.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but you can probably use the `normalize` prop of [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/field.md/#-code-normalize-value-previousvalue-allvalues-previousallvalues-gt-nextvalue-code-optional-) on the input component. Something like:

```
const encryptPassword = (value, previousValue, allValues, previousAllValues) => {
    // Encypt the password somehow
    const encyptedPassword = ...;
    return encyptedPassword
}

<TextInput type="password" normalize={encryptPassword} />
```

Another option would be to transform the payload before sending it to your API in your `dataProvider`. Something like:

```
// in src/dataProvider.js
import dataProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

// defaultDataProvider is your original dataProvider which we decorate here
const addEncryption = defaultDataProvider => (fetchType, resource, params) => {
    let finalParams = params;

    if (resource === 'users' && fetchType === 'CREATE') {
        finalParams = {
            ...params,
            password: encryptPassword(params.password),
        };
    }

    return defaultDataProvider(fetchType, resource, finalParams);
}

export default addEncryption(dataProvider);
```